# Unable to get "schemaXml" for a field using Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api, error, column

I want to get "schemaXml" for a field, using this Rest API:

```
https://***.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/fields?$filter=Name eq '_EndDate'$select=schemaXml
```

But I got this error:

```
{
error: {
code: "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
message: {
lang: "en-US",
value: "The expression "Name eq '_EndDate'$select=schemaXml" is not valid."
}
}
}
```

any advice?

Answer (score 0):

`&` is missing in your REST API endpoint.

Try using:

```
https://***.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/fields?$filter=Title eq '_EndDate'&$select=schemaXml,Title
```

---

**Update**:

First of all use below to check the Title of your column (generally it is the **display name** of column:

```
https://spexplorer.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/fields?$select=Title
```

It should return you result like:

```
<properties>
   <Title> Status </Title>
</properties>
```

Then you can use this Title to filter and get schemaXml like:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/fields?$select=schemaXml&$filter=Title eq 'Status'
```

**Column settings**:

[image]

Comment: If "Name" property is not available, you should use "Title" instead of "Name" to filter for specific field.

Comment: i used title instead of name, but i will get empty result although i have a field with the same title `{
d: {
results: []
}
}`

Comment: Check updated answer. It should help you to get correct results.